# XElement.Element("Leve1/Level2") instead of XElement.Element("Leve1").Element("Level2")

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

If I have the following XML in XElement myXML variable in C#,

```
<Example>
   <Level1>
      <Level2>myvalue</Level2>
   </Level1>
</Example>
```

To get "myvalue" I need to do as below:

```
myXML.Element("Leve1").Element("Level2").Value;
```

Is there any shortcut to do it like:

```
myXML.Element("Leve1/Level2").Value
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath with exactly the same syntax you are after:

```
var myValue = myXML.XPathSelectElement("Level1/Level2").Value;
```

`XPathSelectElement` is extension method, so you need to add `using System.Xml.XPath;` to be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet,

```
//Load xml
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<Example><Level1><Level2>myvalue</Level2</Level1></Example>");

//Run query
var lv2s = (from lv2 in xdoc.Descendants("Level2") select lv2.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend you to use `Descendants`. If you want to apply certain path using `Level1`, you could filter by `Parent` on `Level1`;

```
var elementValue = doc.Descendants("Level2")
    .Where(x => x.Parent.Name == "Level1")
    .Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```